# How to automate four-up photo creation

Tags: photo-editing, photoshop-scripting, image-editing

I've got a large number (about 300) of 4x6 photos that I want to reformat by making each into a 2x3 photo, and making one 4x6 composite image from 4 of these.

(I want to make them smaller because that's the output size I need to work with, and I want to make the composite image because 4x6 is a standard print size and I'll be 1/4 of the cost to print the batch, and then I can just cut each image into the four source images.)

Is there a tool or Photoshop script that I could just point at a directory full of photos to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be automated in Photoshop.

Before you begin make sure all your 4 x 6 images are in one folder, and take a note of the folder location. You may wish to split up the job using several different folders, as this will generate lots of new documents, especially if you have 300 photos!

1. Click *File > Automate > Contact Sheet II*
2. Choose the folder where you saved the images
3. Set the document size in inches, and the ppi as desired
4. Deselect "Use auto spacing", and set the vertical and horizontal spacing to 0
5. Set the columns and rows to 2
6. If you have some images that are orientated portrait and some landscape then select the option to "Rotate for best fit". I didn't need this in the example below.
7. Deselect the option "Use filename as caption"
8. Hit OK and wait.  It can take a while to create the documents.

Now all the documents will be created automatically.

[image]

Here's an example I made with 9 photos of cats, showing the resulting 3 automatically created documents

[image]